# jQuery $.when and $.then unexpected results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `$.when().then()` to process functions in a particular order.  Everything works as expected but if a function in [`when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) requires alot of DOM manipulation or a relatively slow ajax request, the function in [`then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) gets executed before the `when` is complete.  I duplicated the results on JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7ZSrv/3/

`run_last` should be ran last, but as you can see it doesn't.  Am I using when/then incorrectly in this case?  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$.when(
   $.get('/', process1),
   $.get('/', process2),
   $.get('/', process3))
   .then(function(){
         $.get('/echo/html', run_last);
    });
```

fixes the problem. You were passing a directly executed `$.get` request in to `then`, rather than a callback which will run the get request.